# Automatically update ARM templates when Swagger changes

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-api-management

At the moment if I update my API so that I include a query parameter on one of my endpoints, I also need to update the ARM template that is used during the Azure DevOps release pipeline to update APIM.

Is there a way to automatically update the ARM template json based on the updated action methods?

The end goal is to have APIM reflect the changes I made in my action methods, without me having to update things in multiple places (ie. action method AND ARM template).

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question, I'd like to invite you to explore using [Azure API Management DevOps Resource Kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) instead, an official tool maintained by the APIM team.